# Water Jug Problem in AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence

You are given two jugs whose capacity are 5 litre and 3 litre. No jugs have any measuring marks on it. You have one source of water. How can you measure 4 litre of water in 5 litre jug ?

Comment: is this a homework question? I am not really sure how this is on-topic for this site. I would vote to close but my vote is binding, so I'll let the community decide.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about filling water jugs and not psychology, neuroscience, or cognitive science.

Comment: Watch die hard: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BVtQNK_ZUJg

Answer (score 1):

1. Empty the small jug.
2. Fill the large jug.
3. Use the large jug to fill the small jug. This leaves 2L in the large jug and 3L in the small jug.
4. Empty the small jug.
5. Use the large jug to fill the small jug. This leaves 0L in the large jug and 2L in the small jug.
6. Fill the large jug.
7. Use the large jug to fill the small jug. This leaves 4L in the large jug and 3L in the small jug.